# Not plotting elliptic integrals

Tags: plotting

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[mu^2 - Cos[t]^2], t]
CenAng[t_, mu_] := EllipticF[t, 1/(1 - mu^2)]/Sqrt[mu^2 - 1]
ParametricPlot[CenAng[t, mu], {t, 0, Pi/2}, {mu, 1.01, 3}]
```

There is no output, even though particular cases can be obtained here numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CenAng` returns a real value not a vector. You can visualize dependency on t and m:

```
Plot3D[CenAng[t, mu], {t, 0, Pi/2}, {mu, 1.01, 3}]
ContourPlot[CenAng[t, mu], {t, 0, Pi/2}, {mu, 1.01, 3}, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)]
```